# `fwrite` before `imagepng` boils png generation in PHP

Tags: php

I am starting to write about picture generation in PHP. But I ran into a peculiar thing, that if a fwrite is executed before imagepng, the output would be a broken image which cannot be rendered. The code is:

```
<?php
update();
$my_img = imagecreate( 2000, 200 );
$background = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0, 0, 255 );
$text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255, 255, 0 );
$line_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 128, 255, 0 );
imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, time(), $text_colour );
imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );
header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $my_img );

function update() {
    $log_file = fopen("./signature_log.log", "a") or die("issue!");
    fwrite($log_file, print_r(getallheaders(), true) . ','. date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', time()));
    fclose($log_file);
}
```

I don't know where is wrong. Moving fwrite after it fixes the problem.

Comment: Can you check to see if it is a proper PNG image (e.g. save it to a file using curl and check to see if it has the proper header)? I suspect your `update()` function writes something to the script output, messing up the PNG header.

Comment: @lmz exactly. The function outputs something before the header.